# The "add comment" text in case of a question with bounty crosses boundaries

Tags: bug, comments, design, bounties

When a question has an open bounty and no one has commented on the question yet, you see the notice for the status of the bounty and the text/link for "add comment".

You can see it in effect in the following screenshot:

> [image: Bounty]

As you can notice that the `d`s and the `t` of "add comment" are cutting in the notice's borders and invading privacy.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: I got this too on SO, Chrome, OSX.